# Universal binary rewriting system

Tags: computability, turing-machines, strings, computation-models, term-rewriting

What is the simplest example of a rewriting system from binary strings to binary strings

$$f:\Sigma^*\rightarrow\Sigma^*\qquad\Sigma=\{0,1\}$$

that can perform universal computation? Binary string rewriting systems in general can compute any computable function, but I have trouble finding *particular* instances that can by themselves compute any computable function given an appropriate input.  I've seen statements that a class of rewriting systems (e.g., the set of cyclic tag systems) is Turing-complete, but I'm looking for a single rewriting system that is universal.

I was thinking a [self-modifying bitwise cyclic tag system](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag#Self_BCT) might be a candidate, but I'm not sure how to interpret the output of such a system.

Comment: I understood your question as being about string rewriting systems,
such as Chomsky type 0 grammars (Semi-Thue grammars). But none of the
solutions being considered seems to fit. What did you precisely mean
by "*rewriting system from binary strings to binary strings*"? For
Chomsky type 0 grammars, I do not see how it can be achieved, unless
the input is first encoded with another device.

Answer (score 6):

[Rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is a binary rewriting system that can perform universal computation, i.e., it has been [proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110#Interesting_properties) to be universal.  It can be implemented by a finite-state transducer: it needs only finite state.

However, Rule 110 is not a tag system or a cyclic tag system, so this does not provide an instance of a specific binary tag system that is known to be universal.  It might be that examining the proof of universality of Rule 110 could yield such a system, as apparently the proof involves a reduction that goes by way of cyclic tag systems -- though personally I've never read the proof, so this is only speculation.

A side note: From Rule 110, you can construct a particular [queue automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_automaton) that is universal: the queue alphabet is $\{0,1,\$\}$ and contains the state of the cellular automaton (a binary string representing the contents of each cell, followed by $\$$).  I don't know whether it'd be possible to use this to construct a specific tag system that is universal (e.g., if you can find a way to use a tag system to emulate a queue automaton).

Comment: Thank you. Is there an example of a system that manipulates only a finite amount of memory at any given time, e.g. a binary tag system? My understanding is that a non-standard initial state was required to show the rule 110 cellular automaton was universal.

Answer (score 3):

[Binary Combinatory Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_combinatory_logic) is an example with simple rewriting rules.

Comment: Of course! Even simpler, perhaps, would be one based on a single combinator?

http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31883/smallest-possible-universal-combinator/31915#31915

Comment: Any single-combinator formulation will almost certainly have *much* more complicated operational rewriting rules. (The "smallness" of languages such as [Iota and Jot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_and_Jot), for example, is only wrt the *denotational* semantics -- their *operational* semantics are *more* complicated than BCL.)